# How to make 3 line button in the upper left corner of pinterest.com?

Tags: css

I'm talking about the 3 lines and not the button itself. How do you make those 3 lines with pure CSS, not using images, in the upper left corner of pinterest.com? How can I make the 3 lines that fit in that small button space in an elegant way?

Comment: I tried using images but wasn't happy with the results.

Comment: Since it's friday I'm going to skip the "WHAT HAVE YOU TRIED" train and just post this link I found after 5 seconds of googling: http://alwaystwisted.com/post.php?s=2012-05-12-create-a-pure-css-menu-button

Comment: I've already googled that before I posted on SO. It doesn't seem very robust, in that border-bottom: 17px double black; is changing 2 of the lines thicknesses and not all 3. I'm looking for a more elegant solution from the gurus of SO.

Comment: If you don't have Firebug installed, do that - then, when you want to see how you can achieve a certain result, you can inspect the element in question and see how they did it. (In Pinterest's case, they used a button with an image-sprite as the background.)

Comment: http://graphemica.com/%E2%98%B0 -- or -- http://graphemica.com/%E2%89%A1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now with box-shadows and html5 support!
Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/v2w3C/1/

```
<a class="menu"><span class="line"></span></a>
```

And the CSS!

```
.menu {
    border-radius: 3px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    color: #5f5f5f;
    font-weight: bold;
    display: inline-block;
    background-image: linear-gradient(rgb(255, 255, 255), rgb(240, 240, 240));
    width: 36px; 
    height: 30px;
    padding: 2px 0 0 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.menu:hover {
    background-image: linear-gradient(#e63d44,#c11a22);
    box-shadow: 0 1px 3px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.22);
}

.menu .line {
    background: rgb(184,184,184);
    border-radius: 2px;
    box-shadow: 0 5px 0 0 rgb(184, 184, 184), 0 -5px 0 0 rgb(184, 184, 184);    
    display: block;
    margin: 10px auto 0 auto;
    height: 3px;
    width: 16px;
    content: " ";
    overflow: visible;
}

.menu:hover .line {
    background: rgb(255,255,255);
    box-shadow: 0 5px 0 0 rgb(255,255,255), 0 -5px 0 0 rgb(255,255,255);    
}
```

Comment: This is really close but when I check in jsfiddle it's a bit off. http://jsfiddle.net/aLBWV/

Comment: @rotaercz Yeah I only tested locally, jsfiddle may be doing it in HTML5. I'll play with it more later.

Comment: @rotaercz Updated, now with working fiddle. Turns out box-shadow is a more reliable method of duplicating lines.

Answer (score 0):

HTML:
`<div class="line-separator"></div>`

CSS:
`.line-separator {
    height:1px;
    background: #999;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #333;
}`

`background` changes the line color, and `border-bottom` gives it a drop-shadow effect. Adjust the colors to your liking.

Answer (score 0):

There are a ton of ways to do this. But I'm going to post the easiest way I know. It's a unicode character: `&#9776;` and it looks like this: ☰